# I dont understand the error.. I think as far as I know there is a dataType, but I dont see how?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, mapping

[image]

In the code below I hope that I specify correctly whats wrong. I need to be able to call item.departments.dept_Type and that should be possible because of the association that I have made. I don't need to create inner joins on a query to get the data if I understand correctly.
This is my PersonClass

```
    namespace DATALAYER.DataHandler
{

    [Table(Name = "People")]

        public class Person 
        {


        private int _DepartmentID;
        public EntityRef<Department> _Department;
        public Person() { this._Department = new EntityRef<Department>(); }
        private int _ID;
            [Column(IsPrimaryKey =true, Storage ="_ID")]
            public int ID
            {
                get { return this._ID; }
                set { this._ID = value; }
            }
            private string _p_FirstName;
            [Column(Storage = "_p_FirstName")]
            public string p_FirstName
            {
                get { return this._p_FirstName; }
                set { this._p_FirstName = value; }
            }
            private string _LastName;
            [Column(Storage = "_LastName")]
            public string p_LastName
            {
                get { return this._LastName; }
                set { this._LastName = value; }
            }
            private string _EmailAddress;
            [Column(Storage = "_EmailAddress")]
            public string p_EmailAddress
            {
                get { return this._EmailAddress; }
                set { this._EmailAddress = value; }
            }
            private string _Password;
            [Column(Storage = "_Password")]
            public string p_Password
            {
                get { return this._Password; }
                set { this._Password = value; }
            }
            private string _SSID;
            [Column(Storage = "_SSID")]
            public string p_SSID
            {
                get { return this._SSID; }
                set { this._SSID = value; }
            }
            private string _DOB;
            [Column(Storage = "_DOB")]
            public string p_DOB
            {
                get { return this._DOB; }
                set { this._DOB = value; }
            }
            private string _CellNumber;
            [Column(Storage = "_CellNumber")]
            public string p_CellNumber
            {
                get { return this._CellNumber; }
                set { this._CellNumber = value; }
            }

            [Column(Storage = "_DepartmentID", DbType = "Int")]
            public int p_Department_dept_ID
            {
                get { return this._DepartmentID; }
                set { this._DepartmentID = value; }
            }

            [Association(Storage = "_DepartmentID", ThisKey = "p_Department_dept_ID")]
            public Department Department
            {
                get { return this._Department.Entity; }
                set { this._Department.Entity = value; }
            }
    }

}
```

This is my Department code

```
    namespace DATALAYER.DataHandler
{
    [Table(Name = "Departments")]
    public class Department
    {
        //private EntitySet<Person> _Person;
        //public Department()
        //{
        //    this._Person = new EntitySet<Person>();
        //}
        private int _DepartmentID;
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_DepartmentID")]
        public int dept_ID
        {
            get { return this._DepartmentID; }
            set { this._DepartmentID = value; }

        }
        private string _deptType;
        [Column(Storage = "_deptType")]
        public string dept_Type
        {
            get { return this._deptType; }
            set { this._deptType = value; }
        }
        //[Association(Storage = "_Person", OtherKey = "ID")]
        //public EntitySet<Person> Persons
        //{
        //    get { return this._Person; }
        //    set { this._Person.Assign(value); }
        //}

    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm thinking is that there is a problem with datatypes between the primary key of the person and a foreign key the departments. But Since they are both int I don't see how that can be a problem.

If someone can just explain my problem to cleary if Im wrong or something or help me with a solution pls.

Added this class

```
namespace DATALAYER.DataHandler
{
public class SHSdb2 : DataContext
{
    public Table<Person> People;
    public Table<Department> Department;
    //public Table<Address> Address;
    public SHSdb2(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}
```

}
Person table
[image: Person table]
Department table
[image: Department table]

Without this code it works but then I can only call stuff inside the table

```
        [Column(Storage = "_DepartmentID", DbType = "Int")]
    public int p_Department_dept_ID
    {
        get { return this._DepartmentID; }
        set { this._DepartmentID = value; }
    }

    [Association(Storage = "_DepartmentID", ThisKey = "p_Department_dept_ID")]
    public Department Department
    {
        get { return this._Department.Entity; }
        set { this._Department.Entity = value; }
    }
```

Comment: what happens when you step through your code? where does it actually fail?

Comment: What is `SHSdb2`? Are you _really_ using LINQ to SQL? Or perhaps Entity Framework?

Comment: When it enters the foreach

Comment: SHSdb2 is my project name thingy not using entity framework not allowed thats why im using this Linq Mapping approach

Comment: added another class maybe that helps. Not sure about the Minimal, Compete and Verifiable example. if you copy past this you prob just need the database and it should work... I think.

Comment: Did you copy it into a console app and it worked?

Comment: no tried to answer someone

Comment: Can you check the datatype of each column of database tables with DTO properties .

Comment: Added two pictures the datatype in the columns are the same as in the database, can string and nvarchar be the problem???

Comment: In your foreach statement, check if item's properties (except linked Department) is loaded and can be printed?

Comment: That I did do it doesn't because of the relation if I delete the relation then it works fine, that's what led me to think it has to be with the ID's

Comment: I updated the code thing at the top

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I fixed it with this not sure if its a fix or I just lucky if someone can still maybe explain this to me it would be much appreciated.

```
var personQuery =
            from per in db.People
            where per.p_FirstName == "Christian" 
            select per.Department;
```

I'm thinking by specifying that it needs to get the data from department it would allow it in the foreach.